# Retrieval Based Q/A bot

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning

I am trying to train a retrieval based Q/A chat bot using RNN (classification). I tried training for about 1000 steps, but have hardly got any meaning full results (ACC < 10). Basically, I was trying to map the tensorflow [DBPedia example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification.py) over my dataset. (So I turned my Q/A problem to a classification one). DBPedia is a clean and grammatically correct dataset. However, my dataset is full of short forms and grammatical errors / spelling mistakes. I have tried to correct many of them using the [(right/wrongs) words pairs](http://norvig.com/ngrams/spell-errors.txt) and stemming.

I have read that sequence to sequence model works the best for such problems. However, I had not expected the RNN to fail so miserably.

Any ideas why it did ?

[EDIT] : Even Char level CNN gives similar result.